# Pattern Matching in OpenRefine JSON

Tags: openrefine

love OpenRefine and how easy it is to use, just been looking into the Extract / Apply bit and this would come in really useful for what I use OpenRefine for. I was hoping that it would be able to use wild cards to match a pattern in the apply section.

So in the example below, I have a new column called Cluster and in there there are items which will be

```
Test
This is a test title
Test 123
123 Test
```

How can it match these and set the cell to Test Titles, note the text might sometimes be the likes of 1435365736 test title. It won't always have the same start and end, but will have test in the title.

I have tried ./?test./? and also asterix around the test, both to no avail, any help would be appreciated.

```
{
"op": "core/mass-edit",
"engineConfig": {
  "facets": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "name": "Cluster",
      "columnName": "Cluster",
      "query": "test",
      "mode": "text",
      "caseSensitive": false,
      "invert": false
    }
  ],
  "mode": "row-based"
},
"columnName": "Title_Cluster",
"expression": "value",
"edits": [
  {
    "from": [
      "This is a test title"
    ],
    "fromBlank": false,
    "fromError": false,
    "to": "Test Titles"
  }
],
"description": "Mass edit cells in column Title_Cluster"
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I need to warn you that the Extract Operations / Apply Operations facility is not fully developed has a number of limitations if used on anything other than the original data.

Anything that ends up being recorded as a `mass-edit` is unlikely to be useful for replaying on different data. For this use case, I'd suggest using something like the `replace` function with a regex pattern as the string to be replaced, so something like:

```
value.replace(/.*[Tt]est.*/,'Test Titles')
```

or

```
value.replace(/.*test.*/i,'Test Titles')
```

The `i` flag tells regex to ignore case and the square brackets enclose a set of permissible characters.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Tom, so I take it this wouldn't be done in the Extract Operations / Apply Operations facility area, but on the column itself?

Comment: Correct, but verify that it shows up in the Extract Operations area as a discrete command which includes the regex, as opposed to a `mass-edit` operation, which won't be transferable to other projects (it just sets the cells in all the selected rows to the given value).

Comment: Tom, thanks for this, is it possible to have several of the value.replace commands ran at the same time? Would it be something like

value.replace(/.*test.*/i,'Test Titles'),(/.*city.*/i,'City Titles')

Comment: Close. You need to repeat the function name `value.replace(/.*test.*/i,'Test Titles').replace(/.*city.*/i,'City Titles')`. You can chain an arbitrary number of functions like this. You could also do them in successive operations, if that's easier.